# Please check the sentence

Tags: grammar

The sentence is "The application of this capability range from - , - , and -, among others." Is the sentence grammatically correct.

Comment: "ranges"; *application* is singular.

Answer (score 1):

While this sentence is grammatically correct, I'm not sure what you would be referring to and it feels quite unnatural.

As I understand the sentence, you are talking about how one would apply certain capabilities.

However, the word choices make me think that you are intending to talk about the way someone might use a computer application. In which case, I would rephrase the sentence as: "The capabilities of this application consist of **_, _**, and ___, among others."

Here I use the plural, 'capabilities' because the application has more than one of those.